# Does utility "ipconfig" work with DHCP-cache?

Tags: dns, dhcp

I know what utility `ipconfig` works with DNS-cache and I though it also works with DHCP-cache. Like, `/renew` takes address of previously used DHCP-server from register. Is it not the same thing as cache?

Well, maybe `ipconfig` also works with ARP-cache, id on't know..

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS and ARP caches are on your computer. Caching DNS servers can also exist all the way up to the root servers.

The DHCP "*cache*" (aka "*leases*") is a file held on the DHCP server. This is used to ensure that one client will consistently receive one address... rather than a new address each time it asks for one. Without this, you could end up exhausting your address space quickly.

There is no client-side DHCP cache.